# I have an answer, but Stack Exchange won't let me post

Tags: discussion

So I stumbled across a question that had no good answers given. As it turns out, I stumbled across it because I was searching the Internet for an answer for the question myself. Then I continued to work on the problem and solved it. And I'd love to share my answer in that thread!  But someone decided that I need 10 reputation points to provide an answer because the other answers that had been given were "spam" or just plain not good.  Well, gee, that's too bad.

Perhaps I will get two up votes for this question, which would enable me to post my answer to the other question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rhetorical question, not a real Home Improvement question...

Comment: That's an *intended mechanism* to prevent  someone who has just arrived at SE from jumping in and starting to write an answer when they haven't even [taken the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) or gotten familiar with the platform.  It's only on certain questions which have proven themselves to be magnets for *bad* answers from newusers.  **This also applies to highly experienced SE'ers.  Moot himself can't post to a protected question on a stack new to him; *the association bonus doesn't count***.

Answer (score 5):

When you have much higher rep, you will be able to (forced to) see these.

[image]

**Here is why the question was protected.**  One was being posted every week! At that rate, there'd have been another six by the time you answered.

So if you thought the restriction was silly, perhaps you were not aware those were there.

> Rob:  “What are you doing?”
>
> Bucky Katt:  “I’m on mouse patrol.”
>
> Rob:  “We don’t have mice.”
>
> Bucky Katt: (peeved) “We don’t have mice … ***because** I do mouse patrol*.”

Answer (score 3):

It was this one. [Disassemble IKEA Godmorgon drawer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160114/disassemble-ikea-godmorgon-drawer) Now it has an answer. Thank you to all who upvoted my perfectly intentional circumvention of a possibly silly rule. I now vote to close my own question as not being a question. – user3276908